# Strange Behavior of li element in responsive webpage

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Hi I am a novice at coding and am learning by myself at home.  I have run into a problem which I simply cannot solve.

Firstly, here is the codepen link for the site:

http://codepen.io/sheahan/pen/ygKabM

The website is working pretty much seamlessly except for one issue.

Take a look at the 'item' list on the left side of the page.  I have set it up so that on a hover the font color, background color, and font size change (i had to change the padding in order to ensure that the li stayed the same size).  This works fine when the screen size is above 900px.

Now I have made the page responsive and set a media query to change the layout below 900px.  The item list moves to the top of the page with a new format its laid out in a grid rather than a single column.  This looks to work fine except for the last item on the right of each row (item 3 and item 6).  Whenever I hover over it it pushes the next item in line over two spaces to the right leaving two empty spaces.  One of the HTML editors I am using shows the presence of two "ghost" li items that aren't there.

Any guesses?

I'm also open to any comments or criticisms of the site, eager to learn.

Here's the raw code

```
    <html>
  <head>

      <title>Food Supply Company</title>

      <link href="FoodSupplyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" text="text/css"> 

      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Volkhov:700|Alegreya:900" rel="stylesheet">  

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <div class="title">
        <h1>Food Supply Company</h1>
      </div>

        <ul class="menunav">
          <ul class="Products">
            <li><a href="#" >Products</a>
              <ul class="productsnav">
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Fruits</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dry Foods</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Spices</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="AboutUs">
            <li><a href="#" >About Us</a>
              <ul class="aboutusnav">
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Personel</a></li>
          </ul>
            </li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="Contact">
                <li><a href="#" >Contact</a></li>
              </ul>
        </ul>

      <div class="ProductMain">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="logoholder">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/501/32498772122_9137841b84_o.png" alt="Company Logo Letters Only" height="130" width="130"></a>
          </div>
          <div class="sidebarlinks">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
              <li class="lastitem"><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="maincontent">
          <h1 class="productname">Item Name</h1>

          <img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/mango_PNG9168.png" >
          <div class="Attributes">
            <div class="Titles">
              <ul>
                <li>Country:</li>
                <li>Variety:</li>
                <li>Season:</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="Names">
              <ul>
                <li>Australia</li>
                <li>Tastey</li>
                <li>October-December</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
            <div class="Description">
              You can add a description of the item.  Mention the history, the taste and other attributes of the product.
            </div>
        </div>


        </div>
          <div class="foot">
                <div class="footer left">Website Designer<br>Happy Designs Inc.<br>Qatar</div>
                <div class="footer center">&copy Food Supply Company</div>
                <div class="footer right">P.O.Box 11111<br>Doha<br>Qatar</div> 
          </div>
        </div>




</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    Margin:0;    
    padding:0;
    border-radius:5px;   
    font-family: 'Verdana',sans-serif;
}

body{
    background-image: url(https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/470/32498869432_082f3cf148_o.jpg);
    background-size:     cover;              
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.container{
    width: 900px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
}

 h1{
    font-family: 'Alegreya:900','Verdana',sans-serif;
    padding:20px 0 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size:65px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color:coral;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 1px grey;
    Width: 100%;
    margin:10px 0 20px 0;

}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;  
}

p{
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
}

li{
    list-style-type:none;
}

.menunav{
    margin:5px 0 30px 0;
    overflow:auto;
    font-size: 20px; 
}

.menunav a{
    float:left;
    margin:0px 3px 5px 3px;
    width:293px;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255,127,80,0.85);
    color: bisque;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px darkgray;  
}

.menunav a:hover{
    background-color: bisque;
    color: coral;
}

.productsnav, .aboutusnav{
    position:absolute;
    top:134px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    z-index: 1;  
}

.aboutusnav{
    margin-left:298px;
}

.productsnav a, .aboutusnav a{
    width:293px;
    display: none;
    background-color:coral;
}

.Products:hover .productsnav a{
    display:block;
}

.AboutUs:hover .aboutusnav a{
    display:block;
}

.ProductMain{
    position:relative;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom:18px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
}

.sidebar{
    float:left;;
    width:250px;
    margin-left:3px;
}

.sidebar a{
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 228, 196,0.85);
    color:coral;
    font-weight: bold; 
    margin-bottom:5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px darkgray;   
}

.sidebar a:hover{
    color:lightgray;
    background-color:coral; 
    font-size:20px;
    padding:13px 0px;
}


.sidebar .logoholder a{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); 
    box-shadow: none; 
}

.sidebar .logoholder a:hover{ 
    padding:15px 0px 13px 0px;
}

.logoholder img{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); 
}

.lastitem a{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.maincontent {
    background-color:rgba(244,164,96,0.8);
    position:absolute;
    left: 270px;
    height: 99.2%;
    width: 600px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 2px darkgray;
    box-sizing:border-box;

}   

.productname{
    font-size:35px;
    margin:0;
    padding: 20px 0 15px 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    color: bisque;
    border-bottom-style:double;
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-color:bisque;
    box-shadow: none; 
}

.maincontent img{
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height:240px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    margin: 20px -5px 0px 30px;
}

.Attributes{
    position:relative;
    right:-8px;
    top:35px;
    overflow:auto;
    height:auto;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    background-color:rgba(255, 228, 196,0.5) ;
    border-style:inset;
    border-width: 3px;
    margin-bottom:90px;
    width:270px;
}


.Titles, .Names{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height:3.7em; 

}


.Titles li, .Names li{
    border-radius: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:chocolate;
}

.Titles li{
    font-size:17px;
    text-align: center;
}

.Names li{
    padding-left:5px;
}

.Description{
    width:500px;
    height:180px;
    overflow:auto;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 10px 15px ;
    background-color:rgba(255, 228, 196,0.5);
    border-style:inset;
    border-width: 3px;
    color:chocolate;
    line-height:1.5em;
}

.foot{

    width: 860px;
    height:70px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 228, 196,0.9);
    margin: 10px 0px; 
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px darkgray;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
    color:coral;
}

.footer{
    display:inline-block;
    width:33%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    height:100%;
    padding:10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin:-3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height:1.5em;
}

.right{
    text-align: right;
}

.center{
    text-align:center;
}

@media screen and (max-width:920px){

    .container{
    width: 600px;
    margin:auto;
    position:relative;
    }

    .menunav a{
    float:left;
    width:32%;
    }


    .productsnav{
    position:absolute;
    top: 213px;
    }

    .aboutusnav{
    position:absolute;
    top: 213px;
    margin-left:198px;
    }

    .productsnav a, .aboutusnav a{
    width:190px;
    }   

    .ProductMain{
    position: relative;
    height:800px;;
    margin-bottom:18px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    width:600px;

    }

    .logoholder{
        display:none;
    }

    .sidebar{
        width:99%;
        position:relative;
        float:none;
        display:inline-block;
        padding-left:10px;
    }

    .sidebar a{
        width:32%;
        float:left;
        margin-right:5px; 
    }

    .maincontent
    {
        position:static;
        margin-top:15px;
        height:600px;
        width:99%;
    }

    .foot{
        width:100%; 
        padding:0;
        height:90px;
    }

    .footer{
        margin-top:0;
    }

    .left{
        margin-left: 13px;
    }

    .center{
        width:30%;
    }

    .sidebar a:hover{
    color:lightgray;
    background-color:coral; 
    font-size:24px;
    padding:10px 0;      
    }

}
```

Comment: And one more question, I can't get the google fonts that I've linked to in my html file to load on the page.  Any help?

Comment: I don't seem to have any issues like the ones you describe, nothing breaks for me.

Answer (score 0):

A shortest way to resolve the issue is to set `font-size:23px;` for `.sidebar a:hover`

```
.sidebar a:hover{
    color:lightgray;
    background-color:coral; 
    font-size:23px;
    padding:10px 0;      
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/Banzay/pen/YNapZy?editors=1100)